# Error with few arguments while running from ROS a python file

Tags: python, pycharm, ros, robotics

I am new to ROS and I am working with a Jaco 2 robotic arm (model 7 DOF)
Now I am trying to do some stuff to understand better how exactly it works

I found some code here:

[https://github.com/Kinovarobotics/kinova-ros/blob/master/kinova_demo/nodes/kinova_demo/pose_action_client.py][1]

to move the arm but I when I tried to run it from termninal with command : python JacoTutorial.py

I had a weird error that says:

**

```
JacoTutorial.py [-h] [-r] [-v]
                       kinova_robotType [unit] [pose_value [pose_value ...]]
JacoTutorial.py: error: too few arguments
```

**

The problem is that because Pycharm doesnt recognize rospy and all ros libraries I cannot also debug it to see where the problem with the few argument exists...

I thought that maybe the code is only for 6 DOF Jaco but it doesnt seem to have different arguments for different models.

Does anybody face that error in the past ?

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like there is an error with the actual program, you need to pass arguments in the command line to the program to configure it correctly.

If you run `python JacoTutorial.py -h` (`-h` is an argument!), it will display the help prompt with all of the arguments you can pass on the command line. Looks like the only required argument is `kinova_robotType`.